# Extract elements from an array whose keys ends with a particular id in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I extract elements whose key ends with its id?

I want to split an array into two arrays by keys in which every element has a key that ends with its id.

The array:

```
array(
      'key_1' => 'some value 1',
      'key_2' => 'some value 2',
     );
```

Now, I have two Ids, 1 and 2.

Expected arrays:

```
array_one(
      'id' => 1,
      'value' => 'some value 1',
     );

array_two(
      'id' => 2,
      'value' => 'some value 2',
     );
```

Actually, I have a $_POST array from a form. Each key ends with its Id, and I want to separate the main array into two arrays by their Ids.

This is the array I have:

```
    Array
(
    [itemId_1] => 1
    [product_id_1] => 1
    [desc_1] => desc for the first item
    [quantity_1] => 5
    [unit_1] => kilogram
    [priceUnit_1] => 100
    [discount_1] => 0
    [taxCost_1] => 45
    [itemId_2] => 2
    [product_id_2] => 2
    [desc_2] => desc for the second item
    [quantity_2] => 10
    [unit_2] => metre
    [priceUnit_2] => 150
    [discount_2] => 0
    [taxCost_2] => 135
)
```

Now, I want these arrays to save each of them into the database. Arrays must be separated by itemId:

```
    Array
(
    [itemId] => 1
    [product_id] => 1
    [desc] => desc for the first item
    [quantity] => 5
    [unit] => kilogram
    [priceUnit] => 100
    [discount] => 0
    [taxCost] => 45
)

    Array
(
    [itemId] => 2
    [product_id] => 2
    [desc] => desc for the second item
    [quantity] => 10
    [unit] => metre
    [priceUnit] => 150
    [discount] => 0
    [taxCost] => 135
)
```

Comment: We see your "requirements dump", but not your proof of effort/research.  Are array_one and array_two meant to be stored in a parent array?

Comment: No. no need to be stored in a parent array.

Comment: Then you should clarify your exact expected output when you edit your question to include your coding attempt.

Comment: What is going to happen next with this prepared data?

Comment: Now we need to see your coding attempt for this Too Broad question.

Comment: If you have form fields with names like `name_number`, then the earliest problem to fix is your form element naming.  You need to use array syntax (name attributes that end with square braces), so that you can enjoy the function benefits of arrays through your processes.

Comment: Please show us your form, so that we can help fix that and make everything else easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31910397/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/35313025/2943403

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I have done it with this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
           $array{$id[1]} = array();
           $id = explode('_', $key);
           ${"array" . $id[1]}[] = array($id[0] => $value);
        }

        $array1 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array1);
        var_dump($array1);

        $array2 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array2);
        var_dump($array2);
```

This will give me the two arrays:

```
    Array
(
    [itemId] => 1
    [product_id] => 1
    [desc] => desc for the first item
    [quantity] => 5
    [unit] => kilogram
    [priceUnit] => 100
    [discount] => 0
    [taxCost] => 45
)

    Array
(
    [itemId] => 2
    [product_id] => 2
    [desc] => desc for the second item
    [quantity] => 10
    [unit] => metre
    [priceUnit] => 150
    [discount] => 0
    [taxCost] => 135
)
```

Comment: This misses out the `product_id_2` items - or any others with more than 1 `_`.

Comment: Because the product_id is static condition, I can handle it simply.

Comment: How about when the code changes and other items with a `_` are added?  Why handle than specifically when your code can do it?

Comment: The keys are static. The number of the keys will not be change.

Comment: So when someone else changes your code and doesn't realise how your code doesn't work properly, they are going to have to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your array by `foreach` and store result in new array like this.

```
$items = array(
    'key_1' => 'some value 1',
    'key_2' => 'some value 2',
);

$result = array(); 

foreach ($items as $index => $value){
    $id = str_replace('key_','',$index);
    $result['array_'.$id] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'value' => $value,
    ];
}

extract($result); // must return array_1 and array_2
```

Comment: It does not split the main array into two arrays

Comment: @AmirhosseinTarmast you can use [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) method to change array to variables. I update my answer.

Comment: It has been my experience that using variable variables or `extract()` is a symptom of bad coding design.  Why do you need these individual variables? ...you probably don't.

Comment: @mickmackusa He want to result be like this. I prefer to using without `extract()`.